# Print data through Spark SQL taking long time

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have 3 text files in hdfs which I am reading using spark sql and registering them as table. After that I am doing almost 5-6 operations - including joins , group by etc.. And this whole process is taking hardly 6-7 secs. ( Source File size - 3 GB with almost 20 million rows ). 
As a final step of my computation, I am expecting only 1 record in my final rdd - named as acctNPIScr in below code snippet.

My question here is that when I am trying to print this rdd either by registering as table and printing records from table or by this method - acctNPIScr.map(t => "Score: " + t(1)).collect().foreach(println). It is taking very long time - almost 1.5 minute to print 1 record.

Can someone pls help me if I am doing something wrong in printing. What is the best way to print final result from schemardd.

```
..... 
val acctNPIScr = sqlContext.sql(""SELECT party_id, sum(npi_int)/sum(device_priority_new) as  npi_score FROM AcctNPIScoreTemp group by party_id ") 
acctNPIScr.registerTempTable("AcctNPIScore")     

val endtime = System.currentTimeMillis() 
logger.info("Total sql Time :" + (endtime - st))   // this time is hardly 5 secs 

println("start printing") 

val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM AcctNPIScore").collect().foreach(println) 

//acctNPIScr.map(t => "Score: " + t(1)).collect().foreach(println) 

logger.info("Total printing Time :" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - endtime)) // print one record is taking almost 1.5 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

They key here is that all Spark [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#transformations) are lazy.  Only [actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#actions) cause the transformations to be evaluated.

> // this time is hardly 5 seconds

This is because you haven't forced the transformations to be evaluated yet.  That doesn't happen until here `map(t => "Score: " + t(1)).collect()`.  `collect` is an action, so your entire dataset is processed at this point.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It really clarified my doubt.

Comment: How can I do some transformations in earlier steps. What kind of transformations I can use in earlier steps so that my all the data is not evaluated at the end. Is caching table is an action or is that also lazy operation?